# How to write template class in ruby

Tags: c++, ruby, templates, generics, graph

I'm true C/C++ programmer and in this moment I'm learning Ruby language.

I'm trying to create template class in ruby, but Ruby didn't have generic classes or interfaces so I had a problem how to write equivalent to followed C++ graph class:

```
template <class V, class E> struct Graph {  
    // Graph edges struct
    struct Ed : E {
        // vertex number
        int v;
        Ed(E p, int w) : E(p), v(w) { }
    };

    // Graph vertex that is connected to vector of edges
    struct Ve : V, vector<Ed> {};

    // Vector of graph vertex that handle connection to other vertex
    vector<Ve> g;
}
```

Idea is to have `Graph` that vertex and edges inherit from class `V` and class `E`.
`Graph` only should contains vector of existing vertexes, but vertex should be generic because it can be for example city object or geometric lump, and the same is with Edges for example street object.

So my thinking goes to create separate wrappers for each of these classes

```
def Graph
  def initialize(*vertexes)
    @vertexes = vertexes
  end
end

def Vertex
  def initialize(object, *edges)
    @o = object
    @e = edges
  end
end

def Edges
  def initialize(object, vertex)
    @o = object
    @v = vertex
  end
end
```

But if this solution provide access to whole method from `Edge` and `Vertex` classes?
For example `Edge` can be a `Street` object and street can have its own methods like: `speed_limit`, `capacity` or `check_availability` and I don't know how to handle this case and don't rewrite this methods in wrappers for each Edges and/or `Vertex` class.

Comment: Templates are pretty much superfluous in a dynamically typed language like Ruby. I don't quite understand your problem.

Comment: Ruby is a dynamically typed language, you won't need a template in Ruby.

Comment: So is possible to extend Edges Class by typed object in constructor?

Comment: In a dynamically typed language, a function can accept arguments of any type that implement the expected interface. So they could be a derived type or even an unrelated type if the calls can be resolved. So they are much like C++ templates, except that everything is resolved at runtime instead of compile time.